# Facebook post do not open my application when i try from safari even though it works when using facebook application.

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

I have shared some content to Facebook and I am using this POC for that.

```
NSString *title = @"Some Title";
NSString *shareBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nI have rated %@ as %zd/5", self.commentTextView.text, store.name, self.rating];

NSString *storeID = store.ID.description;

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
content.contentTitle = title;
content.contentDescription = shareBody;
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:store.coverImage.medium];
content.placeID = storeID;
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://fb.me/ 137144****85103?store=%@", store.ID]];

FBSDKShareDialog* dialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]])
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic;
dialog.fromViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

Post is successfully shared to Facebook even if Facebook app is installed or not.

The first case is when I am using Facebook app and i click on the shared post, it opens my application(if it is installed) or takes me to iTunes URL.

The second case is Facebook app is not installed on my phone and I use safari to view Facebook and I click on that post. It tries to open the url but redirect me to facebook.com again.

The third case is Facebook app is installed on my phone but still I use safari to view Facebook and I click on that post, it opens facebook app instead of my app.

I need help for Case 2 and 3. Please advise ?

Comment: If you share some contents than you need to app installed in your pone. Otherwise it will ask to app installed. If you open in safari than logout  from browser and login in your app than again check it will work

Comment: sorry can you explain it again.

Comment: How are you redirecting to your app? Using URI Schemes?

Comment: Use Associated Domains for deep-linking. It will solve your problem.

Comment: have you done entry in plist file.